# Click "See All" Link in iTunes with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to use AppleScript to navigate iTunes. This is working thus far, but I am having trouble clicking the "See All" link/text (image below).

You may note that there are two "See All" links, one for iPhone and one for iPad. I am trying to click the one for iPhone.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this code in Script Editor:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "iTunes"
    get static texts of UI elements of UI elements of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1 whose name is "See All"
end tell
```

This should get you all the static texts named "See All". Use trial and error till you get the right one.

The trick I used was to use "static texts of UI elements of UI elements" etc, until I found the static text I was looking for. You should be able to do this with anything. Looking for buttons? Replace `static texts` with `buttons`, etc.